# Request parameter getting null in ajax jquery validation engine in java

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

**jqueryvalidationengine-en.js** :

```
"ajaxUserCall": {
    "url": "ajaxValidateFieldUser",
    // you may want to pass extra data on the ajax call
    "extraData": "name=eric",
    "alertTextOk":"* This user name can be used and is available",
    "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
    "alertTextLoad": "* Validating..., please wait"
}
```

**xyz.html**:

```
<input class="validate[ajax[ajaxUserCall]] text-input" type="text" name="requir" id="requir" title="Text value is required"/>

function beforeCall(form, options){
    if (console)
        console.log("Right before the AJAX form validation call");
    return true;
}
// Called once the server replies to the ajax form validation request
function ajaxValidationCallback(status, form, json, options){
    if (console)
        console.log(status);

    if (status === true) {
        alert("the form is valid!");
        // uncomment these lines to submit the form to form.action
        // form.validationEngine('detach');
        // form.submit();
        // or you may use AJAX again to submit the data
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#formID").validationEngine({
    ajaxFormValidation: true,
    onAjaxFormComplete: ajaxValidationCallback,
    onBeforeAjaxFormValidation: beforeCall
    });
});
```

Above is my html and jqueryengine-en.js code
And in servlet i am getting `request.getParameter("requir")` is null.
Please post me your answers regarding the above problem as i was unable to find much about Jquery validation engine on net and please share some link from where i can study more of it.
Please help me in getting `requestParameter("requir")` with form  text box value.
Thanx in advance.